# Trying to figure out how to use infile.readline() on a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am stuck on this assignment that's related to using `infile.readline()` but I lack the understanding of how it works entirely. My professor has covid and wont be attending zoom calls and doesn't respond to my emails when asking how to use it a bit more in depth. The assignment is supposed to search through a .txt file with state names and their populations. There is a header in the .txt file its supposed to skip as well but id assume if I used the `infile.readline()` I would put a `3` in the `()` so it would be `infile.readline(3)`. But here is what the output is suppose to be (P.S: I'm using wing 101 7.2):

```
"""US 2010 population: 308,143,815
The largest state is California with a population of 35,233,926"""
```

The .txt file has this content:

```
State,Population
Alabama,4779736
Alaska,710231
Arizona,6392017
```

Here is the code that I have (it's quite barren but I think it's a start.)

```
inFile = open("States.txt", "r")
outFile = open ("NumberedStates.txt", "w")

lineNumber = 1
for state in inFile:
    outFile.write(str(lineNumber) + ". " + state)
    lineNumber += 1
    
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: What is the code you have tried and what was the result when that code was run? What are the contents of the `txt` file?

Comment: i have only entered the code above which is to the best of my knowledge but it only copies the data. The .txt file has this:                                                 State,Population          
Alabama,4779736

Comment: Why don’t you try printing `state` In the for loop? And I thought ou were supposed ot be using `infile.readline()` but you don’t seem to be.

Comment: Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Is using readline a requirement?

Comment: Always a good idea to read the documentation. It’s here (worth a bookmakr) https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readline#io.TextIOBase.readline

Comment: yes, readline is a requirement but i don't know how to use it, that's why i haven't put it in my code. also i will check out that question @barny !

Answer (score 0):

Here are the general steps.`readline` reads one line of text on each call until end of file and then returns a blank line "". You can run through the lines like this

```
with open("States.txt") as infile:
    # drop header
    infile.readline()
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = infile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        lines.append(line.strip())
```

`lines` isn't quite what you want - the line needs to be split into fields and population converted to an integer. Once you've converted to table holding `(population, state)` tuples, you can sort to find the largest state and add to find the population total.

Comment: sweet, this would be a good start for me as im just reading up/watching youtube a bit more on how to use readline but this is much appreciated!